# Apache Won't List Full Directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I'm using the Apache on my home Linux computer as a temporary server to share a few files between some friends.  As such I just want a directory listing for these files, along with the sub-directories.  I have the indexes option in the directory paramater, and the directory is viewed.  Problem is, only one sub-directory is viewable, while the others are not listed.  I have the permissions and ownerships of all files and directories the same, but nothing changes.  And if I try to force into the hidden directory, I get a message about not having the necessary permissions.  Any help here?

```
Directory directive from conf file:
    <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
Permissions of Directory:
    drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache users 4096 Jan 22 17:17 DND
    drwxr-xr-x. 11 apache users 4096 Jan 16 08:16 Pathfinder
    -rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache users  119 Jan 19 17:30 README
```

Pathfinder and everything in it show up, and README only works when I push it through the URL.  DND doesn't show, nor does it work when I push it through the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on a hosted solution, so I don't have the access to the "master" Apache config files - although I'm allowed to put `.htaccess` in my subfolders, and allow `Options +Indexes` there. However, even when I do so, files called `README` do not get listed - while files named `Readme` do.

This tells me that probably `README` is disabled somewhere in the top-level Apache setup, and probably via `IndexIgnore`; the problem with that seems to be:

[Re. Can htaccess restore default indexing - PHP Server Side Scripting forum at WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4219280.htm)

> Once you setup IndexIgnore you cannot override it from the sub-folders. Try using order allow,deny for it.

... and I gave this a try:

```
Options +Indexes
<Limit GET POST>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from all
</Limit>
<Files "README">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from all
</Files>
```

, but it seems not even that helps with a file named `README` - at least not with the limited config possibilities I have. Another thing is that there is a `ReadmeName` attribute for `apache` (e.g. [apache2 - Change default ReadmeName in Apache - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/296615/change-default-readmename-in-apache)); which could also cause trouble? Also similar question: [http - Apache do not show README.TXT files in directory listing. How can i enable it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933587/apache-do-not-show-readme-txt-files-in-directory-listing-how-can-i-enable-it)

Anyways, the quick fix for me is to rename the file from allcaps `README` to mixed caps...

Answer (score 1):

It will probably depend on your linux distro, but in Centos 6.X, the default Apache Configuration includes an IndexIgnore directive in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf that excludes all files that start with README.